# Emacs not taking full space inside terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs

Image for description:

[image]

---

If you notice carefully, blue background of gnome-terminal is visible below where emacs ends. This probably means that emacs isn't taking full space inside gnome-terminal. How do I solve it (except setting my terminal background as same color which is an annoying hack)?

Comment: I apologize if I sound too harsh, please fix your captcha. or report it. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.303.32`

Comment: FWIW, I don't notice any "blue background of gnome-terminal ... below where emacs ends". Unless you think this is clear to other readers, maybe consider annotating your screen shot to indicate this blue background portion.

Comment: @Drew below the text which is below the modeline/powerline of emacs. `"C++ requires a type...."` below this.

Comment: OK, I see what looks like a blank line there, and the background color is only slightly different from the black background of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure just from a screenshot, but perhaps the window size of your terminal is not an integer multiple of the line height of the text? If that's the case, then you'll get the same behavior even when emacs isn't running; try using less to view some longish file and see if there's the same gap after the last visible line. You could also try adjusting your terminal's font size to see if that gap changes size.

Answer (score 1):

> This probably means that emacs isn't taking full space inside gnome-terminal.

Probably not. It could happen even when emacs takes full space due to the background color rendering of fringes. For example, you have the same problem on the right side also. Moreover, on the right side this blue fringe becomes thicker below the mode line. All this points to font and line sizes resulting in fractional multiples of the screen size. Emacs is taking the full space but rendering in different colors.

`linum-mode` and mode-line themes often cause this. Besides turning off `linum-mode`, try tweaking font metrics as others have suggested above. Or play with fringe theme colors. Make them same as the main theme's background color. Some themes come with a variable for such tweaking. For example:

```
(setq solarized-distinct-fringe-background t)
```

You'll have to find equivalent variables in your active theme.